# Monitoring routes, hops

Tags: nagios, networking

we're using Nagios and SmokePing to monitor our systems. In case of problems between our office and a hosting facility we can see risen round trip times and packet losses but have no clue what's the cause of the problem.

I have seen that there's SmokeTrace (http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/doc/smoketrace.en.html) that allows trace routes from within SmokePing.

At best there was a tool that monitors routes and records them for later reference constantly.

Does anyboy know about such a tool/plugin, preferred open source?

Thanks!

Clarification:

I would like to have access to a traceroute result or something like that at a later point in time when I get aware that there was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Nagios has a plugin for that](http://vuksan.com/linux/nagios/check_traceroute.txt).

Comment: If I don't get it wrong this plugin does nothing more than tracerouting a given host/IP and grep if there was at least once an answer indicated by a "ms" response time. I don't think that this solves my problem.

Comment: It's a script you can easily edit.  For example, perhaps you know your preferred route.  Instead of grepping the latency, you could grep for your preferred route, and raise an alert if it changes.  You don't even need Nagios to use this script.  You can just use cron to run the script and do something with the output.  I'm not sure if this is going to help you solve your problem - from your question it sounds like you just want to know when the route changes so you can do further manual checks to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try scripting around the MTR command in unix/linux